# How to insert a row in an HTML table body in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, insert, row

I have an HTML table with a header and a footer:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>My Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>aaaaa</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>My footer</td>
        </tr>
    <tfoot>
</table>
```

I am trying to add a row in `tbody` with the following:

```
myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length - 1);
```

but the row is added in the `tfoot` section.

How do I insert `tbody`?

Comment: Tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

Answer (score 317, accepted):

If you want to add a row into the `tbody`, get a reference to it and call its [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) method.

```js
var tbodyRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Insert a row at the end of table
var newRow = tbodyRef.insertRow();

// Insert a cell at the end of the row
var newCell = newRow.insertCell();

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText = document.createTextNode('new row');
newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>My Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>initial row</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>My Footer</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

(old [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4sR2G/) on JSFiddle)

Comment: My code breaks because: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Vrankela: Probably your selector is incorrect (first line in example).

Comment: the above would fail the first time. instead check if there are no rows:    var rows = tableRef.rows;
 var rowsSoFar = (rows==null) ? 0 : rows.length;
 var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(rowsSoFar);

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, How to add css style into textnote ?

Comment: this will show text as html tags. There should be a way with innerhtml to convert text to html. because most cases with dynamic insertions of rows to tables will be html tags.

Comment: this method is slower than document.createElement('tr') , td etc

Comment: Instead of `tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);` you can simple use `tableRef.insertRow(-1);` to insert the row at the end of the table.

Comment: how to insert entire row if i have entire `<tr> ... </tr` html string for all cell? above code seems to add one cell only.

Answer (score 50):

You can try the following snippet using [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

```js
$(table).find('tbody').append("<tr><td>aaaa</td></tr>");
```

Comment: maybe you are right but sometimes you need to know the real stuff :) and as i say always know JavaScript before the using any library no hard feeling body ;)

Comment: I'm trying to apply your answer to my case but I couldn't, so I posted a new question, do you think that you can answer it and save me? ► https://stackoverflow.com/q/63194846/3298930 .

Comment: What is the syntax if I want a variable in place of aaaa?

Comment: ...apend("<tr><td>" + myVar + "</td></tr>");

Answer (score 34):

Basic approach:

This should add HTML-formatted content and show the newly added row.

```
var myHtmlContent = "<h3>hello</h3>"
var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
newRow.innerHTML = myHtmlContent;
```

Comment: My favorite solution: very elegant and with added flexibility to add inner HTML.

Comment: if you have given an id to the tr string then it will remove it so be carfeul.

Answer (score 10):

I think this script is what exactly you need

```
var t = document.getElementById('myTable');
var r =document.createElement('TR');
t.tBodies[0].appendChild(r)
```

Comment: of course you need to modify your new row but i just offered the concept in the answer and left the rest to you :)

Comment: This has the advantage that you can append a cloned row, and avoid creating a new one, in order to maintain the CSS style.

Answer (score 9):

You're close. Just add the row to the `tbody` instead of `table`:

```
myTbody.insertRow();
```

Just get a reference to `tBody` (`myTbody`) before use. Notice that you don't need to pass the last position in a table; it's automatically positioned at the end when omitting argument.

[A live demo is at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdAbJ/).

Answer (score 8):

```js
let myTable = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

let row = myTable.insertRow();
let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

cell1.innerHTML = 1;
cell2.innerHTML = 'JAHID';
cell3.innerHTML = 23;

row = myTable.insertRow();
cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

cell1.innerHTML = 2;
cell2.innerHTML = 'HOSSAIIN';
cell3.innerHTML = 50;
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>AGE</th>
        </tr>    
     </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add rows:

```html
<html>
    <script>
        function addRow() {
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            //var row = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var x = table.insertRow(0);
            var e = table.rows.length-1;
            var l = table.rows[e].cells.length;
            //x.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

            for (var c=0, m=l; c < m; c++) {
                table.rows[0].insertCell(c);
                table.rows[0].cells[c].innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
        }

        function addColumn() {
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
                table.rows[r].insertCell(0);
                table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
        }

        function deleteRow() {
            document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
        }

        function deleteColumn() {
            // var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
                table.rows[r].deleteCell(0); // var table handle
            }
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="row +" onClick="addRow()" border=0 style='cursor:hand'>
        <input type="button" value="row -" onClick='deleteRow()' border=0 style='cursor:hand'>
        <input type="button" value="column +" onClick="addColumn()" border=0 style='cursor:hand'>
        <input type="button" value="column -" onClick='deleteColumn()' border=0 style='cursor:hand'>

        <table  id='myTable' border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr id='myRow'>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And cells.

Comment: I think you should use more sensible variables when creating an example.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the tbody, then insert a new row at the end of it.

Use [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to insert Node or DOMString objects to a new cell, which will then be inserted into the new row.

```js
var myTbody = document.querySelector("#myTable>tbody");
var newRow = myTbody.insertRow();
newRow.insertCell().append("New data");
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>My Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>My footer</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add Column, Add Row, Delete Column, Delete Row. **Simplest way**

```js
    function addColumn(myTable) {
      var table = document.getElementById(myTable);
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
        row[i].innerHTML = row[i].innerHTML + '<td></td>';
      }
    }
    function deleterow(tblId)
    {
        
      var table = document.getElementById(tblId);
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            if(row.length!='1'){
                row[row.length - 1].outerHTML='';
            }
    }
    function deleteColumn(tblId)
    {
        var allRows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
        for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
            if (allRows[i].cells.length > 1) {
                allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    function myFunction(myTable) {
      var table = document.getElementById(myTable);
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      var row = row[row.length-1].outerHTML;
      table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + row;
      var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      var row = row[row.length-1].getElementsByTagName('td');
      for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){
        row[i].innerHTML = '';
      }
    }
```

```css
    table, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    td {
      cursor:text;
      padding:10px;
    }
    td:empty:after{
      content:"Type here...";
      color:#cccccc;
    }
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="+Column" onclick="addColumn('tblSample')">
    <input type="button" value="-Column" onclick="deleteColumn('tblSample')">
    <input type="button" value="+Row" onclick="myFunction('tblSample')">
    <input type="button" value="-Row" onclick="deleterow('tblSample')">
    </p>
    <table id="tblSample" contenteditable><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this, and this is working for me:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(myTable.rows.length-2);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
```

Comment: And what if the footer has 2 rows?

Comment: Ok simple make it as var row=table.insertRow(0); it will add row at top

Comment: @JVerstry tbody: this is exactly what does [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following example:

```
<table id="purches">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Transaction Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Transaction Amount</th>
            <th>Offer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <!--  <tr th:each="person: ${list}"    >
            <td><li th:each="person: ${list}" th:text="|${person.description}|"></li></td>
            <td><li th:each="person: ${list}" th:text="|${person.price}|"></li></td>
            <td><li th:each="person: ${list}" th:text="|${person.available}|"></li></td>
            <td><li th:each="person: ${list}" th:text="|${person.from}|"></li></td>
            </tr>
    -->

    <tbody id="feedback">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/search",
    data: JSON.stringify(search),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (data) {
        //  var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"  + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "</pre>";
        // $('#feedback').html(json);
        //
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        //$("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //$("#feedback").append('<tr><td>' + data[i].accountNumber + '</td><td>' + data[i].category + '</td><td>' + data[i].ssn + '</td></tr>');
            $('#feedback').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].accountNumber + '</td><td>' + data[i].category + '</td><td>' + data[i].ssn + '</td><td>' + data[i].ssn + '</td><td>' + data[i].ssn + '</td></tr>');

            alert(data[i].accountNumber)
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>" + e.responseText + "</pre>";
        $('#feedback').html(json);

        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Expense Tracker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>

    <div id="myDiv">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="myInput"
        id="myInput"
        placeholder="Name of expense"
        size="50"
      /><br /><br />
      <label for="date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="myDate" name="myDate" />
      <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="myAmount"
        id="myAmount"
        placeholder="Dollar amount ($)"
      /><br /><br />
      <span onclick="addRow()" class="addBtn">Add Expense</span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Add Rows" onclick="addRows()" />
    <!-- Optional position -->
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>McDonald's</td>
        <td>6/22/2017</td>
        <td>$12.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      function deleteRow(r) {
        var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
      }
      function addRows() {
        console.log("add rows");
        document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML += `<tr>
        <td>McDonald's</td>
        <td>6/22/2017</td>
        <td>$12.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" />
        </td>
      </tr>`;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#myTable tbody").append(tablerow);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).