# How to change the content of a webpage without using document.write?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a .js file that creates a 4x4 table that way:

```
document.write('<div align="center"><table>');
for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (var b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
        document.write('<td align="center" id="t' +((4 * a) + b) + '"></td>');
    }
    document.write('<\/tr>');
}
```

What if I want to add one column and one row to that table after the page is loaded? In other terms, I'm looking for the same function but the "4" is a variable and I get its value from a checkbox.

(I didn't put that code in a proper function because every time I call document.write in a function, the page goes blank).

Maybe there is another way to use it in a function without document.write and that's what I'm looking for.

So I tried to concat all the '' strings and apply them to the .innerHTML of the table, but it didn't work. Any ideas why? And how can I correct the bug?

Thank you. *(No jQuery answers please...)*

Comment: You might find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript

Comment: Basically using document.write is not such a good idea.

Comment: By just reading the title, as an alternative you can use `document.body.innerHTML="stuff"`...  Although I'm not sure that resolves the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard `document` methods. Documentation can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

CSS

```
table {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
}
td {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var table = document.createElement('table'),
    tHead = document.createElement('thead'),
    tBody = document.createElement('tbody'),
    row,
    cell,
    a,
    b;

table.align = 'center';
table.appendChild(tHead);
table.appendChild(tBody);
for (a = 0; a <= 3; a += 1) {
    row = tBody.insertRow(-1);
    for (b = 0; b <= 3; b += 1) {
        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.id = (4 * a) + b;
        cell.align = 'center';
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cell.id));
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/6Xz33/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working if I insert it in a function. I want to be able to change the number of rows and columns

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle of your changes so I can see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that's working! Then to change the content of each cell, how can I access a cell (outside the function addTable) in order to call appendChild?

Comment: [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Answer (score -1):

```
var main = document.getElementById("table");
document.write('<div align="center" id="table"><table>');
    for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
main.appendChild('<tr>');
    for (var b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
    main.appendChild('<td align="center" id="t' +((4 * a) + b) + '"></td>');
    }
main.appendChild('<\/tr>');
}
```

I'm basically just switching document.write for appendChild(). Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure using simply appendChild() is correct!

Comment: That is incorrect syntax, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Comment: I forgot to define the element and I gave the table a id to be able to add Child to it, edited

Comment: That is not how you use `.appendChild`. `.appendChild` accepts an `HTMLElement` object, not a string.

Comment: Yes that is true. I took this from a old project of mine and now I use jQuery so often that I am confusing that with pure javascript