# Using javascript how to clone all row in table to store in session and append it back

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I do shipping purchase. when user add to cart but not submit yet than user click to other page, I want store items in session.This is my code

```
    var tab=document.getElementById("shippingCartForm");
    var tbody = tab.getElementsByTagName( "tbody" )[ 0 ];
    var row1 = tbody.getElementsByTagName( "tr" )[ 0 ];
    var clnNode=row1.cloneNode(true);
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", clnNode);
```

that is my html

```
    <table id="shippingCartForm"  border="1">
                <thead>
                   <th>No</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
                   <th>Quantity</th>
                   <th>Remove From Cart</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             </tbody>
         </table>
```

So when user click to other page or refresh page. I need chack session if it's has, it's should be show `talbe shippingCartForm` when user back to page purchase.

This is my script

```
    window.onload = function() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("name")!= null){
             var tableRef = document.getElementById('shippingCartForm');
             var newRow = tableRef.getElementsByTagName( "tbody" )[ 0 ];
             tableRef.appendChild(sessionStorage.getItem("name"));
        }
}
```

but I get message errors on console like this

```
[object HTMLTableRowElement] script.js (line 2)
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.
tableRef.appendChild(sessionStorage.getItem("name"));
```

please help me to resole it. thank for any idea.

** JavaScript only no Jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362167/how-to-copy-all-row-in-table-to-store-in-session?noredirect=1#comment56466734_34362167  @ching is it the same thing?

Comment: yes, it is, I re ask again

Comment: You should continue on the same question. Make necessary edits to the same questions. This is something you should follow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript

Comment: oh,, wait, let me try

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  tableRef.appendChild(sessionStorage.getItem("name"));
```

with

```
  newRow.appendChild(sessionStorage.getItem("name"));
```

tableRef is reference to table where as you are fetching reference to tbody in newRow variable. replacement will add row to tbody.

Also remove/delete duplicate question or question with less clarity out of 2 you asked on forum.

Try and debug the script see what values you are getting in each variable.

Comment: Stack overflow not allow me to remove question because It's has answer

Comment: Either of them working for you? If it does accept one of them. I will delete answer then you can remove it.