# JavaScript how to add data to a variable

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var  table = "<tr><td><input type='hidden' class='hid_id' value='"+id+"' /> "+id+
"</td><td>"+document.getElementById("name_"+id).value+
"</td><td>"+document.getElementById("price_"+id).value+
"</td><td><input type='text' id='qua_"+id+
"' value='1' disabled='disabled' /></td><td><button>more</button></td></tr>";
```

to add to table when user click `Addbutton`

```
  <table id="tbForm1"  border="1">
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
  </table>
```

**But** I want store it (var `table`) and assign to other one variable and all row when user click add. How I can ?

**Edit**
I don't know syntax of `JavaScript` but if it's `PHP`, I mean:

```
  $ba .= 'a';
  if(click=='add'){
   $ba .='b';
  }
  echo $ba; //outup ab
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but maybe `document.getElementById("tbForm1").innerHTML` is what you want?

Comment: I think the OP wants to store the whole table to a `var` html and all!

Comment: @Barmar I mean if it's PHP code  `$ba .= 'a';
if(1==1){
 $ba .='b';}if(2==2){
 $ba .= 'c';}else{
 $ba .= ' d';}
echo $ba; //outup abc`

Answer (score 0):

As Vohuman mentioned use that function to create dynamic row with an Id and use below to add that row to another table.

```
var x =document.getElementById("tbForm1").getElementsByTagName('tbody');
x.innerHTML = generateRow(id);
```

Also refer to this to add subsequent rows

[How to insert row in HTML table body in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript)