# javascript constructor for table

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm trying to understand how constructors works. Here is the first part of my table constructor:

```
function build(rowsNum,cellsNum,id){

    this.id=document.getElementById(id);

    this.addRow=function(){
        var row=id.insertRow();

        for(var j=0;j<cellsNum.length;j++){
            var cell=row.insertCell();
        }
    };
}
var test=new build(1,2,firsttbody);
test.addRow();
```

The problem is that the method test.addRow(); don't add cells. I have already checked that my browser supports insertCell(), but I can't understand, what is wrong. In console there are no errors.

Comment: If its not a variable change to `build(1,2,"firsttbody");` as `getElementById()` wants a string.  `cellsNum` is a Number, it has no `length` property. - Your F12 Error Console will help with this.

Comment: `insertRow()` takes an index.  so does `insertCell()`.  You have to tell it what position to do the insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert row in HTML table body in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript)

Comment: @AlexK. error was that cellsNum has no length, I didn't notice that because of fatigue. And with build(1,2,"firsttbody"); I have error: Uncaught TypeError: id.insertRow is not a function

Comment: `this.id` is the element, `id` is its name so `this.id.insertRow(XXX);` where `XXX` is an index you need to provide as mentioned above.

Comment: @AlexK. thank you, it works now!