# Rows are added in thead instead of tbody

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

The following HTML file contains an add button. When clicked, it should add a row. When I inspect the code, I find the rows added under the `thead` not the `tbody` tag. Why is that? how to avoid this?

```js
addButton = document.getElementById("add-button");
table = document.getElementById("data-table");

addButton.addEventListener('click', add, false);

function add() {

  var tableLength = table.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(tableLength);

  var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var col2 = row.insertCell(1);

  col1.innerHTML = "col1";
  col2.innerHTML = "col2";
}

var delLink = document.getElementById("delete-link");
delLink.addEventListener('click', del, false);

function del() {
  var rowstoDelete = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  [].slice.call(rowstoDelete).forEach(function(row) {
    row.remove()
  });

}
```

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data-table" border=1 class="data-table">
  <thead>

    <tr id="head" class="head">
      <th class="head">Name</th>
      <th class="head">Action</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="initial-row" class="initial-row">
      <th><input type="text" id="text-field"></th>
      <th><input type="button" class="add-button" id="add-button" value="Add"></th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>

</table>

<a id="delete-link" href="#"> Delete all rows Except the first two</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert row in HTML table body in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript)

Comment: `insertRow()` appends to the parent of the row identified by the index. Since the existing row is in `thead`, that's what `insertRow()` appends to.

Comment: BTW, you can use `-1` instead of `tableLength` to mean you want to insert at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check my fiddle here
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/panvourtsis/9ma2agu4/)

What you didnt did is to see specifically for tbody. Answered here [How to insert row in HTML table body in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript)

```
    addButton=document.getElementById("add-button");
table=document.getElementById("data-table");

addButton.addEventListener('click',add,false);

function add()
{

    var tableLength=table.length;
    var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertRow(tableLength);

    var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var col2 = row.insertCell(1);

    col1.innerHTML="col1";
    col2.innerHTML="col2";
}

var delLink = document.getElementById("delete-link");
delLink.addEventListener('click',del,false);

function del()
{
    var rowstoDelete = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
    [].slice.call(rowstoDelete).forEach(function(row) {
    row.remove()
    });

}
```

Comment: What is the [0] after the `tbody` for?

Comment: the selection always returns a kind of array (html collection). The tbody is always one in the array (in a correct structure). This gets the first element of the array.