# How to insert array values into a HTML table with a while loop?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, while-loop, html-table

I am trying to put an array in a HTML table with a while loop but it doesn't work and I don't know how it will work. I have to put the names in the second `td`.

```js
var nummer = 0;
var naam = ["Chris Froome", "Rigoberto Urán", "Romian Bardet", "Mikel Landa", "Fabio Aru", "Daniel Martin", "Simon Yates", "Louis Meintjes", "Alberto Contador", "Warren Barguil", "Damiano Caruso", "Nairo Quintana", "Alexis Vuillemonz", "Mikel Nieve", "Emanuel Buchmann", "Brice Feilu", "Bauke Millema", "Carlos Betancur", "Serge Pauwels", "Tiesj Benoot"];

while (nummer <= 20) {
  document.getElementById("naam").innerHTML(naam[0]);
  nummer++;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabel">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Naam</td>
      <td>Team</td>
      <td>Tijd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="naam"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: give every name column an id( "naam0","naam1",..) and use `document.getElementById("naam"+nummer).innerHTML(naam[nummer])`. and use nummer  < 20

Comment: You are continuously over writing the `innerHTML` "Or trying to". You are also always accessing the first element in the array by using `[0]`. Not the method I would use but `document.getElementById("naam").innerHTML+=naam[nummer ];` should fix your current problem

Comment: refer this ans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript

Comment: please accept an answer if one of the questions solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Select only the second cell from each row and iterate over them

```
let names = ["Chris Froome", "Rigoberto Urán", "Romian Bardet", "Mikel Landa", "Fabio Aru", "Daniel Martin", "Simon Yates", "Louis Meintjes", "Alberto Contador", "Warren Barguil", "Damiano Caruso", "Nairo Quintana", "Alexis Vuillemonz", "Mikel Nieve", "Emanuel Buchmann", "Brice Feilu", "Bauke Millema", "Carlos Betancur", "Serge Pauwels", "Tiesj Benoot"];
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:nth-child(2)');
for(let i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
    cells[i].innerHTML = names[i];
}
```

```js
let names = ["Chris Froome", "Rigoberto Urán", "Romian Bardet", "Mikel Landa", "Fabio Aru", "Daniel Martin", "Simon Yates", "Louis Meintjes", "Alberto Contador", "Warren Barguil", "Damiano Caruso", "Nairo Quintana", "Alexis Vuillemonz", "Mikel Nieve", "Emanuel Buchmann", "Brice Feilu", "Bauke Millema", "Carlos Betancur", "Serge Pauwels", "Tiesj Benoot"];
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:nth-child(2)');
for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
  cells[i].innerHTML = names[i];
}
```

```html
<div id="tabel">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Tijd</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="naam"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fgbg9Lac/)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

`document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text`.

- Create the table rows with **JavaScript**.
- The **length** of the table rows is the **length** of the **array**.
- Separate `<thead></thead>` and `<tbody></tbody>`.

### **Example**

```js
var naam = ["Chris Froome", "Rigoberto Urán", "Romian Bardet", "Mikel Landa", "Fabio Aru", "Daniel Martin", "Simon Yates", "Louis Meintjes", "Alberto Contador", "Warren Barguil", "Damiano Caruso", "Nairo Quintana", "Alexis Vuillemonz", "Mikel Nieve", "Emanuel Buchmann", "Brice Feilu", "Bauke Millema", "Carlos Betancur", "Serge Pauwels", "Tiesj Benoot"],
  cols = document.querySelector("#tabel > table > thead > tr").children.length, // Get length of the columns in thead
  tbody = document.querySelector("#tabel > table > tbody");
for (var i = 0; i < naam.length; i += 1) {
  var row = tbody.insertRow(i);
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j += 1) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
    if (j === 1) { // Second td
      var text = document.createTextNode(naam[i]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabel">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Tijd</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Hints**

- [insertCell()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp)
- [insertRow()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)
- [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Answer (score 0):

i use both answer try to compile it as now it work in 2 step

first it draw row and column and then fill data in it it look better that way. and also needed that in that way

```js
var names = ["Chris Froome", "Rigoberto Urán", "Romian Bardet", "Mikel Landa", "Fabio Aru", "Daniel Martin", "Simon Yates", "Louis Meintjes", "Alberto Contador", "Warren Barguil", "Damiano Caruso", "Nairo Quintana", "Alexis Vuillemonz", "Mikel Nieve", "Emanuel Buchmann", "Brice Feilu", "Bauke Millema", "Carlos Betancur", "Serge Pauwels", "Tiesj Benoot"];
var cols = document.getElementById("hea").children.length;

var tbody = document.getElementById("roww");
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
  var row = tbody.insertRow(); //create row
  var obj = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
    obj.push(row.insertCell(j));//create cell & add array
  }
  obj[1].innerHTML = names[i]; //enter detail to cell
}
```

```html
<div id="tabel">
  <table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr id="hea">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Tijd</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="roww">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```