# Displaying array data from session to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've copied data of a html table on page 1 in an array obj(arrData). And i've save that arrData into the session storage. Now on page 2, how do i display the data from the arrData to the html table. New in JS. Thanks in advance

[image]

**PAGE 1 JS**

```
var arrData=[];               
$("#checkout").on('click',function(){

$("#table tr").each(function(){
    var currentRow=$(this);

    var col1_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var col2_value=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var obj={};

    obj.col1=col1_value;
    obj.col2=col2_value;

    arrData.push(obj);
   sessionStorage.myArrData=JSON.stringify(arrData);
 });
console.log(arrData);

});
```

**PAGE 2**

```
<table class="table table-checkout" id="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

**PAGE 2 JS**

```
var arrData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.myArrData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sessionStorage.setItem("foo", 12) rather than sessionStorage.foo = 12;

The latter is attaching a new property to the javascript object, not talking to the browser session API. When the page reloads, the object you attached is gone.

To get the item back, use sessionStorage.getItem

[Mozilla docs for sessionStorage including setItem and getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Once you've done that, you will need a way of creating new table rows in the table. There are a multitude of frameworks for this purpose, but you can also build tables (with a few more steps than with other elements) yourself

[How to insert row in HTML table body in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript)

Comment: i've added the JS for page 2. I've checked the console log for arrData in page2 and it does contain the data table from page 1. The problem i have is how do i transfer them to the html table.

Comment: Ok, I'll expand the answer to cinlude the next stage

Comment: but how do i get the data from the arrData ? i mean how do i place the data value from arrData into newRow.insertCell

Comment: added a picture to clarify what i really want

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from above, You have data in array of objects after `var arrData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.myArrData);`, in below format..

arrData:

```
[
{col1:"Item1", col2:"quantity1"},
{col1:"Item1", col2:"quantity1"},
...
]
```

Now to display this data on Page 2

```
var rows = "";
arrData.map((row)=>{
   var row = '<tr><td>'+row.col1+'</td><td>'+row.col2+'</td></tr>';
   rows = rows+row;
})
var tbody = document.queryselector('#table tbody');
tbody.innerHTML = rows;
```