# Convert Pandas DataFrame to html with all tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, html-table

This HTML has two tables:

```
'<div class="table-wrap"><table class="wrapped confluenceTable"><colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup><tbody><tr><th class="confluenceTh">Run</th><th class="confluenceTh">Date</th><th class="confluenceTh">Version</th><th class="confluenceTh">Model</th><th class="confluenceTh">OverallPrec</th><th class="confluenceTh">OverallRec</th><th class="confluenceTh"><span>PersonPrec</span></th><th class="confluenceTh"><span>Personrec</span></th><th class="confluenceTh">AnimalF1</th><th class="confluenceTh">VehicleF1</th></tr><tr><td class="confluenceTd">PR-191</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>15,3/12/19,15:30</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>1.2.191_abcdefg</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>rfcn_dcn_0221</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.95</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.95</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.98</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.93</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.85</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.85</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="table-wrap"><table class="confluenceTable"><colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup><tbody><tr><th class="confluenceTh">Col1</th><th class="confluenceTh">Col2</th><th class="confluenceTh">Col3</th><th class="confluenceTh"><p>Col4</p></th></tr><tr><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">2</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">3</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">4</td></tr></tbody></table></div>'
```

df1

```
      Run              Date          Version          Model  OverallPrec  OverallRec  PersonPrec  Personrec  AnimalF1  VehicleF1
0  PR-191  15,3/12/19,15:30  1.2.191_abcdefg  rfcn_dcn_0221         0.95        0.95        0.98       0.93      0.85       0.85
```

df2

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     1     2     3     4
```

I want to append a new row to df2

`df2.loc[len(bdf)] = [2,3,4,5]`

and then convert it back to the html for posting. `df2.to_html` doesn't work since it's missing the `<div>`, `class` and many other tags

```
df2.to_html(classes='confluenceTh')
'<table border="1" class="dataframe confluenceTh">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Col1</th>\n      <th>Col2</th>\n      <th>Col3</th>\n      <th>Col4</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>1</td>\n      <td>2</td>\n      <td>3</td>\n      <td>4</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>2</td>\n      <td>3</td>\n      <td>4</td>\n      <td>5</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

Comment: If you want to add a row to an html table, I think going through pandas is the wrong approach.  That said, I'm still not sure what your expected result is.

Comment: the result would be a new row added to the table on the page, what's a better approach?

Comment: javascript probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-row-in-html-table-body-in-javascript

Comment: oh no it has to be in python, I can use different modules but not a different language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with html as strings, a convenient option is to work with an html parser, such as beautifulsoup.

You can make a copy of one of the table row for modification, allowing you to essentially skip through ensuring the consistency of class and other tags manually.

```
import bs4
import copy


test = '<div class="table-wrap"><table class="wrapped confluenceTable"><colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup><tbody><tr><th class="confluenceTh">Run</th><th class="confluenceTh">Date</th><th class="confluenceTh">Version</th><th class="confluenceTh">Model</th><th class="confluenceTh">OverallPrec</th><th class="confluenceTh">OverallRec</th><th class="confluenceTh"><span>PersonPrec</span></th><th class="confluenceTh"><span>Personrec</span></th><th class="confluenceTh">AnimalF1</th><th class="confluenceTh">VehicleF1</th></tr><tr><td class="confluenceTd">PR-191</td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>15,3/12/19,15:30</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>1.2.191_abcdefg</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>rfcn_dcn_0221</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.95</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.95</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.98</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.93</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.85</span></td><td class="confluenceTd"><span>0.85</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="table-wrap"><table class="confluenceTable"><colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup><tbody><tr><th class="confluenceTh">Col1</th><th class="confluenceTh">Col2</th><th class="confluenceTh">Col3</th><th class="confluenceTh"><p>Col4</p></th></tr><tr><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">2</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">3</td><td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">4</td></tr></tbody></table></div>'

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(test)
tbl = soup.findAll('table')
table_body = tbl[-1].find('tbody') #select last table
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

new_row = copy.deepcopy(rows[-1]) #select last row, and make a copy

#mutate that copy
cols = new_row.find_all('td')
new_data = [2, 3, 4, 5]
for col, data in zip(cols, new_data):
    col.string = str(data)

table_body.append(new_row) #append at the end of last table selected earlier

with open(r"D:\python\html.html","w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Having said that, it is rare you would need to append to an html after it is parsed in this manner, usually you have more control "upstream" so to speak, before/during html creation. So i would recommend exploring that as an option, either using templates if server side, or javascript for client side.