# How to insert row in table through Javascript function

Tags: javascript, nodes

I am trying to insert another row into a table with footer.

Here is my code:

```
function submit(){
        /* Some code here with declarations & value assignings*/

        let tble = document.getElementById("tabl");
        
        let newEl = document.createElement("tr");
        newEl.innerHTML="<td>"+nowSr+"</td> <td>"+taskForm+"</td> <td>"+tagForm+"</td> <td>Rs. "+amountForm+"</td>";

        tble.appendChild(newEl, tble.lastElementChild.previousSibling.lastElementChild);
       }
```

My function gives me below result:
[image]
[image]

As you can see (IN INSPECT ELEMENTS WINDOW) the new row is inserted after the footer. How to add it properly

- after the last row in the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a row in an HTML table body in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333427/how-to-insert-a-row-in-an-html-table-body-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't insert the element directly to the `<table>` element, but select the `<tbody>` instead.

You can do that like that:

```
function submit(){
  let tble = document.getElementById("tabl");
        
  let newEl = document.createElement("tr");
  newEl.innerHTML="<td>"+nowSr+"</td> <td>"+taskForm+"</td> <td>"+tagForm+"</td> <td>Rs. "+amountForm+"</td>";

  tble.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(newEl, tble.lastElementChild.previousSibling.lastElementChild);
}
```

But you shouldn't use `innerHTML` to create the row (it could create an XSS vulnerability), use `innerText` or `textContent` instead. But that means that you have to create the `<td>`s differently:

```
function submit(){
  let tble = document.getElementById("tabl");
        
  let newEl = document.createElement("tr");
  appendTD(newEl, nowSr);
  appendTD(newEl, taskForm);
  appendTD(newEl, tagForm);
  appendTD(newEl, "Rs. "+amountForm);

  tble.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(newEl, tble.lastElementChild.previousSibling.lastElementChild);
}

function appendTD(tr, text){
  const td = document.createElement('td')
  td.innerText = text
  tr.appendChild(td)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It Solves it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try puhsing to the `tbody` intead of the table directly

```js
function addTableRow(){
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody')
  
  const newRow = document.createElement('tr')
  newRow.innerHTML = `<td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td>`
  tbody.appendChild(newRow)
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Helo</th>
      <th>World</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="addTableRow()">Add row</button>
```